# Bootstrap меню. Часть текста не ушел под мобильной меню

Tags: bootstrap

Всем привет. Друзья не подскажите как сделать часть кода где меню сайта не все ушел под мобильной меню. Хочу чтобы Sign Up и Login был там где на примере.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Отредактируйте пожалуйста вопрос, чтобы можна было без усилия и вчитывания в каждое слово понять, чего вы хотите. И покажите, какая часть кода у вас уже есть и что у вас конкретно не получается.

Comment: Изменил. Спасибо за совет.

Comment: как вариант иожете добавить `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>` перед вашей менюшкой только с классом например `show_only_mobile`, и показывать эти два блока тогда, когда вы схлопываете меню.